Ubuntu end of life: will snap applications still receive updates?
When a Ubuntu version reaches end of life (EOL) it stops receiving APT updates.
Does this apply to the snap store as well, that is, when Ubuntu is EOL does $ sudo snap refresh stop working?

Questions about EOL versions of Ubuntu are off-topic here. You should always use supported versions. However, I think snaps will still be updated since snaps are platform independent. Also, you can easily find out by trying it yourself.

@mook765 23.10 is EOL today and I remember reading somewhere 24.04.1 is scheduled for release in around a month from now. I'm waiting for that. I don't want to upgrade now and risk breaking my current environment only to spend time fixing something which has to be done when I fresh install 24.04.1.

@David That seems to apply only to LTS. And the link provided doesn't mention snap applications specifically.

@Daniel seems you may have misread the 24.04 Release Notes. 23.10 users should release-upgrade immediately, as that upgrade path is tested and open and 23.10 will end support later this month. 23.10 release-upgrades are NOT related to 24.04.1 LTS-to-LTS release-upgrades are currently in testing, and those will become available with 24.04.1. "risk breaking my current environment" may not be mitigated by waiting for 24.04.1

Snap packages will continue to receive updates, whilst your deb based system underneath is still in sync with the snapstore where snap packages come from. If a change is made, as you're not receiving any deb updates your system will start using an outdated procedure and thus newer snap packages may not be detected/installed correctly; but when and if this occurs is unknown. Many snap updates can be handled within the snap packages themselves, and only some come from deb base.  ie. snap updates will occur for atime, but will stop

If you're still using 23.10 (the box I'm using now was until recently; I'm not on my primary box), I suggest release-upgrade asap and not waiting, as the upgrade from 23.10 o 24.04 was MINOR, why upgrades opened soon after.. The upgrades from the prior cycle include changes from 22.10/23.04/23.10 plus what 23.10 users have thus the delay.. (QA on that upgrade is still occurring; 23.10 to 24.04 was deemed stable long ago).  If you're worried about apparmor issues; those are only found/fixed after a user reports bugs on the app & new rule is created.

Correction: Ubuntu 23.10 reaches EOL 2024-07-11. That's today, not later this month.

I don't see the point of closing this question, apart from being pedantic...

@Daniel You could dual boot. You can install a new version fresh alongside your recent, fully configured version. That gives you time to work on your old sysytem when needed and explore and configure the new version when you have time to do so.

@ArturMeinild Users should keep up to date and use supported versions of Ubuntu. Running unsupported versions of Ubuntu introduces security risks and is therfore discouraged. Users shouldn't be encouraged to use EOL versions but should udgrade asap. That's probably the main reason why questions about EOL releases are off-topic. Also you cannot guarantee that snap updates will always work as statet in a comment above.

Snap packages are sandboxed and isolated from the apt package management system. Snap packages are permitted to have other snap packages as dependencies. Their dependencies, libraries and runtime environments are installed when the snap package is installed. This isolation ensures that snap packages can be updated independently of the base system without affecting other system components.
Therefore you can update them freely with sudo snap refresh, even if your Ubuntu distribution is end of life for apt packages. Alternatively you can upgrade an individual snap package like snapd with a command of the form sudo snap refresh snapd. You should keep the snapd package up to date because all of the other snap packages depend on it.

Yes, I know that questions about EOL releases of Ubuntu are off topic, but the question is of general interest like How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release? .

General interest is that users keep up to date and use supported versions of Ubuntu. Running unsupported versions of Ubuntu introduces security risks and is therfore discouraged. Users shouldn't be encouraged to use EOL versions but should udgrade asap.
